# SELECT from mysql database on javascript call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a small web app built in PHP and Javascript/jQuery.

The app involves a random number generator and when it lands on say number 4, the user wins.

However the prize is pulled from a database and after 5 prizes a day are won. the user is unable to win.

Once a user wins, the prize is updated as 'queued' until they have filled out a form and claimed the prize. It is then taken out of available prizes.

This all works fine if the user refreshes the app. However if a user begins to play the app and another user wins then the app wont update unless its refreshed as PHP is server side.

I have a javascript function OnStart. So if i could perform the SQL query here it would happen everytime the user throws the die.

How can I run a php statement from a jquery function?

If it helps here is the statement:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prizes WHERE dateavailable='$todayDate' AND queue='0' AND won='0' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{   
    $prize = $row['prize'];
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:

So could I possibly use something like this with the php in a seperate file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function performAjaxSubmission() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'file.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'save',
        arg1: 'val1',
        arg2: 'val2'
      },
      success: function() {
        alert("success!");
      }
    });
    return false; // <--- important, prevents the link's href (hash in this example) from executing.
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#linkToClick").click(performAjaxSubmission);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to look into jQuery's AJAX capabilities.

Comment: Don't forget to protect your data from SQL Injection.

Comment: so if a user wins, can he still play and win again?

Comment: yes. but he cannot claim a prize twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the posted code in a php file, let's call it `prizes_available.php`. This file should also output whether prizes are available or not, so create the result object and assign the value to it:

```
$result = new stdclass();
$result->prizes_available = $prize != null;
echo json_encode($result);
```

If you call this script in browser, it will output something like this:

```
{ prizess_available: true }
```

Using jQuery, you can easily convert this string into an object again:

```
$.getJSON('prizes_available.php', function(result)  {
    if (!result.prizes_available) {
        alert('no more prizes');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Is there a way i can pass the variables from the SELECT query back into the page where i make the call?

Comment: Yes, you can add them all to an array and then assign the array to the `$result` object.

Comment: I managed to work that out. Thanks for your all your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX, jQuery contains some easy to use functions for working with AJAX.

Usage is simple, you can read about that in [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com)

If you want pass some array to your js script, look for JSON functions (`$.getJSON` in jQuery, `json_decode` / `json_encode` in PHP)

Comment: I have made en edit to the question. Can I use something like that?

Comment: yes, I thing that is what you need. try to change it according to your needs and in case it would not work, I (we) will help you. (sorry for my english, hope you understand me :)