# Display a switch by a flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, twig

I need to display a switch if a flag in my database is setted to a positive value.

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row vertical-padding10">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2 col-sm-12">Switch</label>
                            <input id="switch" name="switch" data-switch="true" data-size="small" data-on-color="success"  type="checkbox" checked>   
</div>
```

How can I execute a query and display this switch in my view? Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you create the variable `$displaySwitch` that indicates if the boolean with true value exists and pass it to the template:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$displaySwitch = $em->getRepository(<your entity class>)->findBy(['<your bool field>' => true]);
return $this->render('<your template>',['displaySwitch' => $displaySwitch]);
```

In the template, add the condition: if no values with true found, don't display the switch:

```
{% if displaySwitch %}
<div class="form-group m-form__group row vertical-padding10">
    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2 col-sm-12">Switch</label>
    <input id="switch" name="switch" data-switch="true" data-size="small" data-on-color="success"  type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add :

```html
{% if value >= 0 %}
    put your input here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i need to execute a query inside my view, that's the problem

Comment: You can't do that in the twig file

Comment: Well you could do it in the view but you shouldn't

Comment: You can use JS to display your value check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298737/select-from-mysql-database-on-javascript-call